# Xcode crashes when distributing app to app store

Tags: xcode, validation, crash, titanium, distribute

I am on xcode 4.6.3 and my team member is on xcode 4.6,

we are having problems when we try and distribute the archive to the app store via xcode organiser...if we hit 'validate' nothing happens, if we hit 'distribute' xcode just crashes and quits.

we have been able to publish to the appstore successfully in the past so are familiar with how it is supposed to work. Recently our ios certificates expired and we had to renew. All new certificates and provisioning profiles have been created and linked together. They all show up as valid in xcode with green ticks next to them, everything seems to be perfect on paper. Its just that nothing has worked since renewing. We are not getting any valuable error messages back from xcode.

It might also help to mention this is a Titanium project, though i suspect it is not the problem here as this project has previously validated properly before the certificate/provisioning profile renewals

additionally, if i try and build to my device it installs and then fails right at the last minute. if i try and drag it to my device / applications in xcode i get the error: "this application does not have a valid signature"

any ideas?, we are going crazy here, nothing seems to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this issue.

After stuffing around with certificates for days **we resolved this by stripping things right back to essentials.**

1. compiled basic hello world in pure xcode and it distributed
2. compiled basic hello world in titanium and it distributed

so we could rule out the certificates, xcode and titanium, it must have been a problem with the project. We would have done this sooner but the projects had previously compiled and it really looked at the time like it was a certificate issue.

**solution:** it turned out that there was an extra Info.plist file in our titanium /resources directory that was now out of date (possibly referencing old certificates?) and overwriting the one in the titanium /build folder, once we deleted the Info.plist, cleaned and rebuilt the project everything was sweet again.